# play video in chkeditor 5 in asp mvc

Tags: video

I need chkeditor5 play video files such as mp4 after the file is uploaded with chkfinder and inserted into chkeditor.Is there any way? Now just the url of the video file is added to the chkediter.

[link of video that is uploaded using chkfinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsweV.png)

I have added embed plugin and this is not my need. I need for example to play a mp4 video file that is uploaded with chkfinder to chkeditor. Your mentioned plugin just supports youtube and instagram and some other websites video. I need something like video plugin in chkeditor4 that creates a video html5 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the docs as it is pretty well written: Here is the [Docs for media embed](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html)

Comment: I have added embed plugin and this is not my need. I need for example to play a mp4 video file that is uploaded with chkfinder to chkeditor. Your mentioned plugin just supports youtube and instagram and some other websites video. I need something like video plugin in chkeditor4 that creates a video html5 tag.